# How do I use the Watson Assistant API with React Native?

Tags: react-native, authentication, curl, fetch-api, watson-assistant

If I attempt to import and use code that invokes the [Watson Assistant API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2?code=node) for Node, I get a fatal error

> The package at "node_modules/ibm-watson/lib/common.js" attempted to
>   import the Node standard library module "os". It failed because React
>   Native does not include the Node standard library.

I [gather](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo) this means that it is not possible to use the Watson Node API with React Native.

What alternatives are available for using the Watson Assistant API with React Native? Should I just use `fetch` and follow the [Watson Assistant cURL API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2), and if so, how do construct the arguments to `fetch`, specifically `-u "apikey:{apikey}"`?

---

There is [partial example](https://dev.to/tonydiaz/building-a-chatbot-using-react-native-and-watson-assistant-3adj) of how to do this with version 1 of the Assistant API, but that uses a different authentication method and is not applicable here.

Comment: I see that the answer to the second part of this question is simply to use a [conversion tool](https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/); but the first part remains: can I indeed not use the Node API with React Native?

Comment: This bug continues with `v5.0.0` of `ibm-watson`.